# Deploying Lagom Microservices on Kubernetes

Tags: maven, docker, kubernetes, fabric8, lagom

I'm trying to deploy Lagom microservices on Kubernetes by following-up the Chirper Lagom example. So According to the provided guide [link](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/lagom-kubernetes-k8s-deploy-microservices/), I configured a kubernetes cluster by installing Minikube and everything is good.

But when I tried to build Chirper Docker images by using fabric8’s docker-maven-plugin, I got this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.1:build (default-cli) on project
>   friend-impl: Execution default-cli of goal
>   io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.1:build failed: No 
>   given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, no read/writable
>   '/var/run/docker.sock' or '//./pipe/docker_engine' and no external
>   provider like Docker machine configured -> [Help 1]

Is there anyone that can help me to understand that error? Thanks.

Comment: This mostly an issue with Docker CLI not able to reach Docker engine. Since you are using Minikube, you can use `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command so that Docker CLI points to Docker engine in Minikube and builds images within Minikube VM

Comment: @VishalBiyani, I configured minikube on another PC, so I thought that I only need to install Docker on my PC of dev to build my images. So it is work when I executed eval $(minikube docker-env) and I rebuilt my project on the PC that contains minikube. Thank you

Comment: I have added it as an answer so others benefit from it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updating based on discussions in comments]

The issue here is that the Docker CLI is not able to reach the Docker Engine. Since you are using Minikube, you can point docker CLI to Docker engine inside Minikube. That will ensure that images are built inside minikube VM and also ran there subsequently. You can run command:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

This command will set the parameters required by Docker CLI to communicate with Docker engine in Minikube and it should be able to run command which is failing for you!